# How to control odoo 10 from command line while its running in the web

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, odoo-10

I'm running ODOO 10 from source code in Eclipse on Windows 10. It's running ok in the web interface (on localhost)

I want to control the odoo via command line at the same time. Can I do so while its running in the web interface?

If so how do I invoke the odoo commands to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out: You go to the root directory where the source is located and where the odoo-bin python file is, together with the odooshell (which you change to batch) and run it as follows:

```
python odoo-bin --help
```

And take it from there!

When the debugger is running it seems not to work, but if the server is running outside the debugger (in Eclipse I hit "run" with a run configuration) then  the command line works ok.

for example, in windows open cmd and 
    C:> CD c:\myDevPath\odoo 
    C:\myDevPath\odoo>
    C:\myDevPath\odoo> python odoo-bin --i18n-import=addons\point_of_sale\i18n\he.po --i18n-overwrite -l=he --database=odoo --db_user=mydbUser --db_password=myodoodbPassword

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

python ./odoo-bin -c odoo.conf

Hope this help you